# when i am opening a file using vi editor its showing error in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, vi

vi Linked.c
"has(" [Not edited] --No lines in buffer--
Error detected while processing /home/pi/.vimrc:
line   13:
E580: :endif without :if: endif
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: So maybe remove your `~/.vimrc` file, which appears to have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cp ~/.vimrc ~/.vimrcold
rm -f ~/.vimrc
```

Actually i am using nano editor on my rpi and i have a couple of them.
Good luck